# Testing negation in the null hypothesis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Is it valid to state a null hypothesis as the negation of an equality?

Something like:

$$H_0: \mu_1\neq \mu_2\,\,\,\,\,\,vs\,\,\,\,\,\, H_1:\mu_1=\mu_2.$$

Comment: This is going to be problematic - your null is composite and your alternative is simple. Consider the mechanics of choosing the rejection region for this test. You want the significance level not to exceed some chosen [test size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_(statistics)). So you need to choose your rejection rule based on the supremum of the rejection rate when the null is true. Where in parameter space will that supremum be? If your test is to have power, that will be at the boundary of the null and the alternative, but this boundary *is* the alternative; you'll compare it with itself.

Comment: To make things a little more concrete, you might like to try to construct a likelihood ratio test for a simple situation of this kind and investigate its properties

Comment: I expect you'll get a good answer, but if not I may be able to come and turn that into something of an answer with an example.

Comment: If you wish to look for evidence that quantities are equivalent against a null that quantities differ by at least some amount check out the [Two One-Sided Tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info) approach to tests for equivalence. And welcome to CV.